# Windows 10 2004 using powershell-7.0 to update help files

Tags: windows-10, updates, help-files, powershell-7.0

On Windows 10 v2004, within PowerShell 7.0.3 x64, I don't know why it's showing the resource as unavailable:

```powershell
PS > Update-help -UICulture en-US

     Update-Help: Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender, PSReadline, WindowsUpdateProvider' with UI culture(s) {en-US}:
       One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.).).

     English-US help content is available and can be installed using: 
       Update-Help -UICulture en-US
```

Comment: As a comment, [404 Status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) are returned by the remote server being contacted. Arguably, the logical inferences are likely either the Powershell command itself is broken and providing the wrong URLs or there is remote server issue.

Comment: I got a different error but the same idea, all other help files updated just fine, it's just those 3 modules that it seems to be unable to get the required update files: ```Update-help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender, PSReadline, WindowsUpdateProvider' with UI culture(s) {en-US} : Unable to retrieve the HelpInfo XML file for UI culture en-US. Make
sure the HelpInfoUri property in the module manifest is valid or check your network connection and then try the command again.```

Comment: @Anaksunaman I know that the issue is at 'their end' as I know what 404 error codes stand for. Maybe you can connect to good old MS and let them know of the issue.

Comment: Yep, I did get the same errors everytime I tried to run Get-Help...

Answer (score -1):

This has been going on forever and this is the best I have been able to find for a workaround:

```powershell
Update-Help -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: All that means is that PowerShell won't warn you if it fails. It doesn't change the actual outcome of what OP is experiencing.